# configuring Search Settings for all Site Collections once

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

If you want that all site collections will point to the Search Site, do you need to configure all Site Collections one by one? Is there any way (powershell or something) which you can use once to configure all site collection? thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you are looking for. I have used this when I had to recreate my search center and it worked like a charm:

http://sharepoint.jsturges.com/2012/02/update-search-center-for-all-sites-in-a-web-application/

All you basically do is save your new search center url in a variable and use that variable to set the url to all sites within a web app by iterating through them.

Comment: I looked to the link you sent. it looks interesting. I upvote your answer. Ok do I need run a script every time I create a SC?

Comment: Well, if your search center is going to be named differently or in a different place then YES you would have to run this script to set the new search cetner as the default search center on all your site collections.

Comment: I will be having same Search Center on same place. so What I need to do when i create a new Site Collection in my farm?

Comment: Two ways to handle it if you were to create new site collections: 1. If you are creating only one or two Site Collections, you can go to site actions>>site settings>>search settings (under site collection Administration) and set your Search Center there. 2. If you are goign to create a bunch of site collections, then just run the script again.